# Django.db import error

Tags: python, django

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    if not settings.DATABASES:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
    self._setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

How can I set the environment variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

["Standalone Django scripts"](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/)